# Lyapunov Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\dot{x}=v(x)$ with $v(x)=Ax+O(\left \| x \right \|^2)$, $v\in C^k(U)$, $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $  n\geq 2$, is true or not that if the origin is a singular point Lyapunov stable for $\dot{x}=Ax$? then is a point Lyapunov stable for $\dot{x}=v(x)$

I think this is false, let

${x}'=-y+x^3 \\ {y}'=x+y^3$

so we have the origin is a singular point Lyapunov stable for $\dot{x}=Ax$ because if I take $g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+1>0$ then I have $\bigtriangledown g(x,y)(-y,x)=0$ then the origin is Lyapunov stable, then I would find another $g´$ such that $g´(x,y)({x}',{y}')>0$  bye Lyapunov´s Stability theorem I will have that the origin is not stable, well that´s my idea, I just want to know if I'm on the right way
Thanks for any comments!

Comment: In my opinion the origin is unstable.

Comment: yes, the origin of all de system is unstable, the origin of the linear part is stable, but the origin of all is unstable, that is why i need the $g´$ to prove it.

Answer (score 5):

If $\dot x = Ax$ is stable at the origin in the sense of Lyapunov, there exists a positive definite $P$ matrix such that $AP + A^TP \leq 0$.

For the case where the Lyapunov equation is $AP + A^TP < 0$, If $v(x)$ can be written as $v(x) = Ax + O(||x||^2||)$, where $O(||x||^2) \to 0$ when $||x|| \to 0$ (Taylor series residue), then the Jacobian of the system $\dot x = v(x)$ about the origin is $A$, which is Hurwitz and therefore the system is stable about the origin. Note that there is not any information about the region of convergence.

On the other hand, if you can not find such $P$ for $AP + A^TP < 0$, but the system is stable in the sense of Lyapunov, you have that $AP + A^TP = 0$. Therefore, $A$ is not Hurwitz, but its eigenvalues have negative real part and zero real part (they are on the imaginary axis). Therefore, checking the stability of the non-linear system $\dot x = v(x)$ via the Jacobian fails, and you have to go for other analysis tool such as Centre Manifold theory.

For the first case, the system is stable about the origin. In the second case you can not assert that the system is stable or unstable only checking the linearization of the system about the origin.

Answer (score 2):

The statement you are trying to assess is whether a point that is Lyapunov stable for the system with $\dot{x}=Ax$ remains Lyapunov stable when perturbed by a term $O(\|x\|^2)$ as given in the form $\dot{x}=v(x)=Ax+O(\|x\|^2)$. The example you provided illustrates that this statement is not necessarily true.

In your example, the system is described by:

\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= -y + x^3 \\
\dot{y} &= x + y^3
\end{align*}

The origin is Lyapunov stable for the linearized system $\dot{x}=Ax$ (i.e., when $y=0$, $\dot{x}=-x$) as you correctly pointed out using the Lyapunov function $g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+1$.

However, when you add the nonlinear term ($O(\|x\|^2$)) to the system, the origin is no longer Lyapunov stable. To demonstrate this, you would need to find a Lyapunov function $g'(x,y)$ such that its derivative along the trajectories of the perturbed system $\dot{x}=Ax+O(\|x\|^2)$ is not strictly negative. This can indeed be challenging in some cases, and your example serves as a counterexample to the claim that Lyapunov stability is preserved under such perturbations.

So, in summary, you are correct in your analysis, and the statement is false. The origin being Lyapunov stable for $\dot{x}=Ax$ does not necessarily imply that it remains Lyapunov stable when perturbed by a term $O(\|x\|^2)$ as in $\dot{x}=v(x)$. Your example demonstrates that it is possible for the stability to change when nonlinear terms are added to the system.